Quarkus: Stopping server process: Dev mode process did not complete successfully
IntellIJ 2024.1.4, Quarkus 3.12.1, Maven 3.9.8
Clicking button in IntellIJ to stop Quarkus example getting-started:
Failed to execute goal io.quarkus.platform:quarkus-maven-plugin:3.12.1:dev (default-cli) on project getting-started: Failed to run: Dev mode process did not complete successfully

More details
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: Failed to run
    at io.quarkus.maven.DevMojo.execute (DevMojo.java:500)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:316)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:162)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:63237', transport: 'socket'

Already issue, see https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/14647, but no solution

Tried on plain command without an IDE?
